# Android soundboard error

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

My tasks run through and it runs fine up to the last few sounds.  for some odd reason it keeps force closing, I have looked and looked and don't get why. I took sounds away and did several other steps and I don't understand is there a size limit or something?

It is the second program it has done it on, any ideas?

```
MediaPlayer mp1, mp2, mp3, mp4, mp5, mp6, mp7, mp8, mp9, mp10, mp11, mp12,
    mp13, mp14, mp15, mp16, mp17, mp18, mp19, mp20, mp21, mp22, mp23, mp24, mp25, 
    mp26, mp27, mp28;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

  //set up the button sound
    mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.backtoyou);

    //button 1 coding 
    ImageButton Button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById (R.id.button01);
    Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp1.start();

        }
    });
    //longclick creates ringtone notification
    //Button1.setLongClickable(true);


    //set up the button sound
    mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.blow);

    //button 1 coding 
    ImageButton Button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById (R.id.button02);
    Button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp2.start();

        }
    });

     //set up the button sound
    mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.boomstick);

    //button 1 coding 
    ImageButton Button3 = (ImageButton) findViewById (R.id.button03);
    Button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp3.start();

        }
    });

    //set up the button sound
    mp4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.byebye);

    //button 1 coding 
    ImageButton Button4 = (ImageButton) findViewById (R.id.button04);
    Button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp4.start();

        }
    });
```

.... And so on and so forth.  So where is the error for the files and why does it keep force closing?

Comment: Can you post the logcat messages that are produced when the app crashes?

Comment: null pointer exceptions are the only ones that it lists, but i am pretty sure it all boils down to too many instances of media players open that crash it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that having 28 `MediaPlayer` objects is eating up a lot of memory. Consider using a `MediaPlayer` objects that gets re-initialized with a new sound each time the button is pressed. Check out this article: http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/08/android-soundpool-vs-mediaplayer-focus-on-soundboards-and-memory-problems/

Comment: In no way did I or the article suggest using a soundpool

Comment: I used the stealthcopter link and did some more research, my way could have worked but was very inefficient, and I am using a whole new style.  Thank you for this link.

Comment: It continued to force close, i used the code that stealthcopter put out there, and he even answered some of my comments but I am still producing one mediaplayer per ever time i use onclick.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you definitely have FAR too many MediaPlayer objects and redundant code. The question I would ask is if you ever need sounds to overlap. For a soundboard, I would assume not (and really, if you did, I'd think that would be an annoying UI quirk -- one I've seen many times).

Try something to this effect:

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
Resources res = getResources();

//just keep them in the same order, e.g. button01 is tied to backtoyou
int[] buttonIds = { R.id.button01, R.id.button02, R.id.button03 /*etc...*/ };
int[] soundIds = { R.raw.backtoyou, R.raw.blow, R.raw.boomstick /*etc...*/ };

View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //find the index that matches the button's ID, and then reset
        //the MediaPlayer instance, set the data source to the corresponding
        //sound effect, prepare it, and start it playing.
        for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
            if(v.getId() == buttonIds[i]) {
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(soundIds[i]);
                player.reset();
                player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                player.prepare();
                player.start();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

//set the same listener for every button ID, no need
//to keep a reference to every button
for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
    Button soundButton = (Button)findViewById(buttonIds[i]);
    soundButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: All of the code compiles fine except it has an issue with the listener, what variable do I define as the listener globally so it has no problems?

Comment: I placed this straight into the Oncreate activity, Im new to java is that where i was supposed to implement this.

Comment: Well, this was just an off the top of my head suggestion, not necessarily meant to compile as is. You'll need to move the listener definition in front of where you try to set the listener (e.g. move the setOnClickListener for loop after the listener declaration).

Comment: Okay so more the for loop to where, Sorry, I keep trying to move it around and its just not connecting for me.

Comment: I edited the post to show how to move it. Basically, before, it was trying to set an OnClickListener that hadn't actually been defined yet.